# How to configure Phpstorm to use Beyond Compare

Tags: merge, phpstorm, beyondcompare3

How can I configure PHPStorm 6 to use Beyond Compare 3 (standard edition) by default?

I figured that I need to go to Settings->External Diff Tools
then choose the executable path on both comparing files and folders
but main problem is with the merge parameters - what are they?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*JetBraind Php Storm 6.0*
*Beyound Compare 3*

Parameters: **%1 %3 %2 %4**

Comment: In case anyone else finds this whilst looking for setup instructions for the diff side of things, not just merge, note that PHPStorm doesn't need you to add parameters for diff - just give the path to the executable on its own.